# why the queue can not works for communication in this multiprocess case

Tags: python, queue, multiprocess

The following code is about the communication between two child processes by queue. I can not figure it out that why the self.q.qsize() is zero and self.q.get() is blocked in the Function "ACT"???....  Since the  counter shows the queue is full...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from multiprocessing import Process
import multiprocessing
import time
from Queue import Queue

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.q = Queue(1)

    def ACT(self):
        while True:
            print "B momoent queue size: %s" %self.q.qsize()
            print self.q.get()
            time.sleep(1)

    def counter(self):
        for i in range(5,10):
            if not i == 5:
                print "Hello1"
            print self.q.full()
            self.q.join()
            print "Hello2"
            self.q.put(str(i))
            print "A moment queue size: %s" % self.q.qsize()         
if __name__ == '__main__':

    foo = Test()
    qw = Process(target=foo.counter)   
    qw.start()

    qr = Process(target=foo.ACT)
    qr.start()

    qw.join()
    print "End"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue).

*[`Queue.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue) is meant for threading use.* Right now you are creating and using separate queue instances in each process - there is no logic to facilitate the inter-process communication that `multiprocessing.Queue` provides.

`multiprocessing.Queue` mirrors most of `Queue.Queue` methods but you will have to remove `join` method call and possibly `qsize` if on OS X.

Comment: But the self.q = Queue(1) is declared in the init part of the Class, and you mean when I call the second Process for "pr" this self.q is fork but not sharing the same memory???     If the truth is not like this, Please give me more help on this conception...

Comment: @PuMing.Z Correct, while it may share the same memory on certain OSes initially via copy-on-write, changing one will not change the other.

Comment: You mean the deepcopy?  I appreciate for your help on this.  I am keeping going coding now...ha